# manifest is picking predifined redist

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

i am developing a software using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition. after build in release mode, i have made a setup file with latest redist 2008. the software is running in my PC fine. in my PC this redist are installed :

[image]

in my friends PC, the same redist are installed. but the software is crashing on my friends PC.

[image]

from the event log it shows:

[image]

as you can see, it is demanding 9.0.21022.8 version of redist whether there is previously  installed latest version of redist(9.0.30729.17). so, i go for a google. from the internet, i edit my **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtassem.h**

[image]

but it didn't help. then i check  my project manifest. and i saw :

[image]

but i don't know how to edit manifest (i am new in VC++). and i also check **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest**. i shows:

[image]

i have tried to find out 9.0.21022.8 version of redist in the internet. but i have failed. from my VCExpress installer there is a file named **vcredistmin_x86.exe** :

[image]

as you can see the version of the file is 9.0.21022.8. i think this is the redist i need. but i cannot install it. it says "run the setup.exe file"

what can i do?

**Edit(if i am asking two different answer from this question, please inform me. i will delete this edited part):**

i am now wanting to deploy my project from `Microsoft Visual studio 2008`. i have uninstalled previous `Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 express edition`. but when i am trying to install `Microsoft Visual studio 2008`, it says

> Installation Requirements:
>
> A compatible version of Visual Studio 2008 was not detected on the
>   system. This update is designed for only the Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2008 (ENU) product family, and is not compatible with any Express
>   editions.

guys, have you any idea what to do?

Comment: Note "DebugCRT" in the message.  You don't get that one with the redist, it is only included with Visual Studio.  Only ever deploy the Release build of your programs.  If you want it to be intentionally slow for some reason then just turn off the optimizer.

Comment: then what should i do ? i am completely new with VC++ @HansPassant

Comment: Change the drop-down box in the Visual Studio toolbar to say "Release" instead of "Debug". Rebuild your application. Look in the `bin\Release` folder to find the EXE, and give that to your friend instead.

Comment: i have done that, but it says `side by side configuration is incorrect`. which i have mentioned in my question. @CodyGray

Comment: The message says DebugCRT, like Hans pointed out. So obviously you're not building a Release build.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see this download is 9.0.21022.8: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

I don't know about VS Express, in VS full version there are the vcredist_x86/x64/arm.exe available in the install directory (For VS2012: .../Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\redist\1033)

Comment: i have done that, but the version is still showing 9.0.21022 not 9.0.21022.8 :( @MofX

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable for you, the simplest way to forget about this problems you can statically link with Runtime by changing your project properties: C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library, select /MT or /MTd. Runtime library will be included into your executable so you won't have to install it on client machine.

Comment: i cannot do this. because i need `/MDd`, cause i need `/clr` command. i cannot modify that because previous team has done a lots of thing using `/clr` @Andy T